# Python Tkinter Label Position

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My problem is that I cannot put possition on the Tkinter window. For defining a x and y position I use .place function

I use .place for define a position what i want, but that didn't work. I cannot find any information about that, even i StackOverflow.

My code: Python

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

# window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x550+800+550")
window.title("Python Tkinter widget")
window.resizable(False, False)

# widget1
widget1 = ttk.Label(master = window)
label1 = ttk.Label(master = widget1,text="NEWS",  font="Calibri 18 bold")
label1.pack()
widget1.pack(pady = 10)

# widget 2
widget2 = ttk.Label(master = window)
miniwidget1 = ttk.Label(master = widget2)
miniwidget2 = ttk.Label(master = widget2)

# -miniwidget1
label2 = ttk.Label(master = miniwidget1, text = "CROATIA IN BEST EUROPEAN DESTINATION RACE", font="Calibri 25 bold")
label2.place(x=60, y=60)
miniwidget1.pack()
miniwidget2.pack()
widget2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

For complete this project or practice, i use miniwidget1 and miniwidget2 to define left and right side. On the left have to be text, were on the right side is like a content.

Here is a picture what I'm trying to make, for now i want "basic" like it was on the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf0ve.png)

My output of the Tkinter Widget is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJWBo.png)

How to fix it?

PS. I want this solution of this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM6HN.png)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems, but they all stem from not using any options when calling `pack`.

The first problem is that `widget2` doesn't fill the whole window. It remains just big enough to hold its children. From the picture it looks like you want it to fill everything below the title. You need to use the `fill` and `expand` options like so:

```
widget2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

You have the same problem with `miniwidget1` and `miniwidget2`. In addition, because you don't give them a size and don't use `pack` or `grid` to place other widgets in them, they are each one pixel tall and wide. If you configure them to fill the available space you don't have to worry about giving them a size.

```
miniwidget1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
miniwidget2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

When solving layout problems it helps to temporarily give widgets distinctive colors. For example, if you temporarily switch to tk frames and give `miniwidget1` and `miniwidget2` it makes it easier to see the results of these changes:

```
miniwidget1 = Label(master = widget2, bg="pink")
miniwidget2 = Label(master = widget2, bg="blue")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This very colourful example shows you how you could use the grid layout manager to create the type of layout you are looking for.

Also using the Frame widget allows you to create "boxes" within the layout that can have their own contents and can be treated as component that you can place anywhere without disturbing their contents.

Make sure to only ever use one of grid, pack or place, best not to mix the layout managers.

```
import tkinter as tk

# window
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x550+800+550")
window.title("Python Tkinter widget")
window.resizable(False, False)

#widget1 - Header
widget1 = tk.Label(master=window,text="NEWS")
widget1.grid(row=0,column=0)

#widget2 - Parent containing two columns
widget2 = tk.Frame(master=window,bg="yellow",width=200,height=100)
widget2.grid(row=1,column=0,ipadx=20,ipady=20)

#widget3 - left hand side of widget 2
widget3 = tk.Frame(master=widget2,bg="red",width=200,height=100)
widget3.grid(row=1,column=0)
tk.Label(widget3,text='content1')

#widget4 - right hand side of widget 3
widget4 = tk.Frame(master=widget2,bg="blue",width=200,height=100)
widget4.grid(row=1,column=1)
tk.Label(widget4,text='content2')



window.mainloop()
```

You can of course remove the colors, they are just to show you the different Frames and how widget3 and widget4 are inside widget3

Comment: You seem to have posted the same answer twice.

Comment: @BryanOakley How strange. Deleted one.